# Heroku: dbm.error: db type is dbm.gnu, but the module is not available

Tags: heroku, celery, kombu

How do l fix the error below? Looks like it has to be installed by Heroku.Do l have to send an email to heroku to install? or nothing can be done about it?

```
2017-03-26T13:04:08.185159+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Starting process with command `celery -A PROJECT beat -l info`
2017-03-26T13:04:08.855433+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-26T13:04:10.745747+00:00 app[beat.1]: celery beat v4.0.2 (latentcall) is starting.
2017-03-26T13:04:11.205764+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `celery -A PROJECT worker -l info`
2017-03-26T13:04:11.793866+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-26T13:04:11.899690+00:00 app[beat.1]: Stale pidfile exists - Removing it.
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957510+00:00 app[beat.1]: __    -    ... __   -        _
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957513+00:00 app[beat.1]: LocalTime -> 2017-03-26 13:04:11
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957513+00:00 app[beat.1]: Configuration ->
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957514+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . broker -> redis://h:**@ec2-74-21-542-46.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4109//
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957515+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957516+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957517+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . db -> celerybeat-schedule
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957517+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
2017-03-26T13:04:11.957536+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
2017-03-26T13:04:11.958413+00:00 app[beat.1]: [2017-03-26 13:04:11,958: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964761+00:00 app[beat.1]: [2017-03-26 13:04:11,963: ERROR/MainProcess] Removing corrupted schedule file 'celerybeat-schedule': error('db type is dbm.gnu, but the module is not available',)
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964763+00:00 app[beat.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964764+00:00 app[beat.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964765+00:00 app[beat.1]:     return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964766+00:00 app[beat.1]: KeyError: 'scheduler'
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964767+00:00 app[beat.1]: 
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964768+00:00 app[beat.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964768+00:00 app[beat.1]: 
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964769+00:00 app[beat.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964770+00:00 app[beat.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 425, in setup_schedule
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964770+00:00 app[beat.1]:     self._store = self._open_schedule()
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964771+00:00 app[beat.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 415, in _open_schedule
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964772+00:00 app[beat.1]:     return self.persistence.open(self.schedule_filename, writeback=True)
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964773+00:00 app[beat.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 243, in open
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964773+00:00 app[beat.1]:     return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964774+00:00 app[beat.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964775+00:00 app[beat.1]:     Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964776+00:00 app[beat.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/dbm/__init__.py", line 91, in open
2017-03-26T13:04:11.964776+00:00 app[beat.1]:     "available".format(result))
```

Answer (score 3):

you should add src/celerybeat-schedule to .gitignore